# A more efficient way of querying for a set match for multiple columns

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Basically what I want to do is the Sequelize's equivalent of this question:

[More efficient way of querying for this data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546464/more-efficient-way-of-querying-for-this-data)

My use case is a bit different from the above question though, much more troublesome. In particular:

1. Unlike the original question, I use MySQL.
2. My case could potentially have not just a pair of values, but a set of up to 4 different values (number of values in each set are not fixed), all thanks to my company's *immaculate* database
3. The maximum amount of sets is not just limited to ~100 sets. I can see this easily exceeds 2000 sets. (this is my main concern)

This query is a part of a already rather complex function. I tried to trim the thing down as much as possible already, but it still take quite a while to do. This query would be triggered, in my estimation, 5 to 7 times throughout the runtime of the function. I have tried the following:

- The conventional way of just stuffing the processed search set inside of [Op.or] would fire up a really long query, which could exceed MySQL's query line limit (I'm not allowed to change this).
- Querying item by item is reliable but slower.

The main function right now runs in approximately 1 minute (note that this is me using a smaller set of data for the purpose of testing, actual runtime can easily be 4-5 times this), which I don't think is acceptable as it is called multiple times a day. I also can't heavily modify the database itself, as it is a legacy database which is also used by other applications. If the original database had been designed properly, we wouldn't have gone to this, but alas, I can only try my best.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe title can be renamed as "...querying for a set match for multiple columns".  "for data within an array of object" sounds like a different things to me.  I am not an English speaker, so maybe I am not suggesting the best, though.

Comment: I'm not really an English speaker either, so it's fine. Good suggestion, I'll fix the title

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use tuple in WHERE clause and you can fill the missing value with `ANY_VALUE(attribute name)` to match anything.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees 
WHERE (name, age, dept, salary) IN (
    ('Alice', 40, ANY_VALUE(dept), ANY_VALUE(salary)),
    ('Bob', ANY_VALUE(age), 'Tech', 120),
    ('Mike', 25, 'HR', ANY_VALUE(salary))
)
```

I tested with 100k data with 1k criterion and the query returns with `2.954s` on my laptop.

========================================================

**UPDATE**

If you always have 4 values and no needs of `ANY_VALUE`, it can write in Sequelize with least `literal`.

```js
const criteria = [
    ['Alice', 40, 'Tech', 120],
    ['Bob', 30, 'Tech', 120],
    ['Mike', 25, 'HR', 120]
];

const result = await db.Employee.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('(name, age, dept, salary)'), Op.in, [criteria])
});
```

However, in your case, the set doesn't guarantee to have all 4 values, thus needs `ANY_VALUE`. Unfortunately, I cannot use `Sequelize.fn('ANY_VALUE', 'name')` in `Sequelize.where` as it tries to escape it and it cannot be escaped.

Therefore, the 3rd argument for `Sequelize.where` also need to be replaced with `literal`. At this point, the code is mostly `literal` and I don't see any differences to just using `Sequelize.query` unless if you are using many other options such as offset, limit, attributes... that can still benefit the Sequelize's query generator.

```js
const result = await db.sequelize.query(`
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE (name, age, dept, salary) IN (${constructedCriteria})`, 
    { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT } // This will let Sequelize to format the response as in `findAll` function.
);
```

Some thoughts.

- What is the use case of >1k criterion? Are all 1k criterion distinct?
- Maybe this scenario is more suited with search engine like ElasticSearch? (if your situation is flexible)

Comment: This could still have `query line limit` issue, but you can split the criteria by X numbers and concat the result.

Comment: This technique can be used indeed in raw SQL. However what I'm asking for is for solutions written with Sequelize. It absolutely can be used to write raw queries, yes, but then the result wouldn't be as nice. But still, thank you very much.

Comment: "the result", do you mean how the response is formatted? or result of using the raw SQL as a consequence?  the former should not matter as sequelize.query will still go through Sequelize's formatter. 

i could write this in Sequelize but not 100% sure.  I can try tomorrow.